# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying not being called during scrolling UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll, avaudioplayer

One of my views is a `UITableView` which acts as the delegate for an `AVAudioPlayer` and this table essentially plays sounds when you select a certain row with options to repeat the sound after its finished playing.

However, I noticed that if I select a cell with repeat ON for a certain sound and then scroll through the `UITableView` to select a different sound, it will not call `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` (and therefore not repeat) until after scrolling has stopped.  As soon as I stop scrolling, it repeats just fine.  Or if I don't scroll at all, it repeats just fine.

What could be happening during scrolling that the `UITableView` is no longer acting as the delegate and calling `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the documentation did not stated it clearly, I suspect that the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` call is deferred on the main thread (bold sentence by me):

> The AVAudioPlayer class lets you play
>   sound in any audio format available in
>   iPhone OS. You use a delegate to
>   handle interruptions (such as an
>   incoming phone call) and to **update the
>   user interface when a sound has
>   finished playing**. The delegate methods
>   for the AVAudioPlayer class are
>   described in AVAudioPlayerDelegate
>   Protocol Reference.

As long as there are some events to process, like scrolling events, the call is awaiting on the main thread.